# What are face normals?

Tags: normals, terminology

I've seen the term `Normal` being used in many places, but I'm not quite sure what it is or what it's used for; what exactly are they?

Comment: read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29 and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Normals_and_Shading

Comment: Already did. That's mostly were the answer originated from.

Answer (score 8):

[*Normals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Normal_to_surfaces_in_3D_space) are vectors that are [*Orthogonal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) to the *[Tangent plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space)* of a curved surface; Or simply *orthogonal* to a *face*.

**The Normals are** usually **used** to determine a surface's orientation toward a light source **for shading**. Most common examples:

- Flat, Goraud, Phong shading

  [image]
- Fresnel, Refraction, Reflection effects
- Bump, Normal, Displacement mapping

Normals are generally normalized to length 1 (in arbitrary units), otherwise calculation errors, and thus artifacts, may arise. Since they only point one way they are also used for back [visibility culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) (when double-sided is off).

That's why it is important for the normals to be consistent and coherent (i.e. point in the correct way - outwards of a model).

Comment: Normals are also used for bump and (duh) normal mapping and smooth shading.

Comment: @PGmath well, yeah... Those were just some examples.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Yea, it felt kind of dumb saying that normal maps mess with normals.  But then again, when I first saw a normal map I thought “that doesn't look very normal to me!”

Answer (score 5):

Besides the mathematical explanations, I think a picture will help to understand what is meant by normals and perpendicular. The faces having a normal (blue lines) pointing to a light source are rendered brighter than the faces pointing into other directions.

[image]

You can toggle the display of normals in the *Properties Panel* (right panel <kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: +1 if you also add screenshot showing how you turn on the normal lines display.