# How to add textures to a collada file imported from Fuse

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I purchased Fuse Character Creator and made a rigged model that I imported into Blender from Fuse. The model is a Collada File and it comes in fine, the model comes rigged and is fully poseable except that the textures aren't applied. I switch to texture view but still nothing. Here's how fuse works, you upload your model to their site, have it autorigged, and then choose the format that you want the model file in. I chose Collada. It then gives you the zip folder with the model and the textures in their own folder named "textures". I don't know what to do from here. The textures are all PNG's. When I exported to as an obj file the model came with the textures applied, but the obj doesn't come rigged. I included a picture of the textures if it helps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**In order for the textures to appear on the object, you must assign a material that uses the textures.**

Here is how you would set up such a material if you are using the cycles render engine.

First go to the *materials* section of the *properties* view, and click *new* to add a new material.
[image]

Then go to the *node editor* and use a node setup like this to combine the textures.
[image]

The main color of the material comes from the *diffuse shader*, which gets its color from the *image texture* node plugged into its *color* input.  This texture should be the one labeled "diffuse".

The gloss map (usually called specularity map, or spec map for short) is used to denote glossiness across the model.  To implement this you use it as the *factor* of a *mix shader* between a diffuse and a glossy shader.  Make sure the glossy shader is in the bottom socket, since the factor value is the fraction of the **second** input that contributes to the output.  If you want more control you can add a *color ramp* node between the image texture and the mix shader and play with the values.

Finally normal maps are used for altering the surface [normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals) to fake small bumps on the object.  The red and green channels of the texture are used to define the x and y components of the normal vector at each point.  To use a normal map simply plug it into the *color* input of a *normal map* node and plug the *normal* output into the *normal* input of the shaders you want it to affect, in this case all of them (the duffuse and glossy).

Comment: Thanls I'm gonna give this a try

Comment: @luigi I just noticed you have both specular *and* gloss maps.  I am not sure what the difference is, since glossiness and specularity are technically the exact same thing.

Comment: Hey so I just added a new image. Check it out. It apparently already has the textures in the material section you told me about. For some reason they don't work though.I'm still trying to replicate your answer though because maybe the textures already being there means nothing. Also I want to then export this model into Unity. Not sure if the whole cycles render engine will be a problem

Comment: @luigi  I don't know why they are not showing up.  It looks like it is using the Blender internal (BI) render engine, I don't know much about BI, I just use cycles so that is what my answer uses.

Comment: @luigi Try going into edit mode (with [Tab]) and selecting all ([A] toggles select/deselect), then go to the UV/image editor.  Is there anything there besides a blank checkered background?  I would think that Fuse would unwrap the model but that's all I can think of.

Comment: it's blank. I did try opening the image in the textures folder earlier but it didn't work. However, I just thought of a solution, let me know if you think it'll work. I can maybe use the untextured model to make my animations. Then I can export those animations into Unity. From there I can import my Fuse model directly into Unity and use mecanim to animate the character there. MIf you don't know Unity or Fuse then this might be a little confusing, but i really think it'll work

Comment: @luigi That's your problem, you have to UV unwrap the model.  That's basically cutting up the model with *seams* and then flattening it out onto the texture so Blender knows which parts of the texture go where on the model.  I will add how to unwrap a model when I get the time, I unfortunately don't have time now.  But you can probably find some good tutorials if you search YouTube for "Blender UV unwrapping tutorials".

Comment: I've actually UV unwrapped before. I honestly think i have it down by memory. My problem is that how will that fix it? Am I going to have to unwrap and guess where the parts go? I assume it will only work if I unwrap it the same way mixamo did.

Comment: @luigi Yea, unfortunately you will have to figure out how it is supposed to be unwrapped based on the pelts of the textures given.