# How to import a collada model with textures?

Tags: texturing, import, collada

I have found very good collada model [here](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=35c94a7dde651c8812d8d820b7b8189d). It comes with the texture files.

But, when I import it into Blender, it has no textures at all.

[image]

So, how to import collada model with textures into Blender?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I know for the [similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/how-to-add-textures-to-a-collada-file-imported-from-fuse). but I don't need to add textures after, I need to import them properly...

Comment: Nope, I have read that one first. I don't need to add textures after, I need to import them properly...

Comment: Does you model have any materials? Do the materials have any textures? Do the textures show when rendered? Is the viewport in the correct shading mode?

Comment: Also see [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541) interchange file formats are not meant to export textures/materials