# textures are not loaded with collada files

Tags: texturing, collada

I'm using Noesis to export Collada files and then import them into Blender 2.82 but the textures are not loaded at all. Is there a way to force the system to load textures?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add textures to a collada file imported from Fuse](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/how-to-add-textures-to-a-collada-file-imported-from-fuse)

Answer (score 1):

.dae files do not contain any textures or texture information other than the (absolute or relative) path to those textures. It's actually quite the same as with many other texture formats (.obj or even .blend, if you choose not to pack your textures into the .blend file explicitly).

It's more of a Noesis question, that is, if Noesis is capable of exporting absolute or relative texture paths. Try to export the .dae file into the same folder that contains the textures. Also check if there are any settings for exporting UV layouts.

If importing the resulting .dae file still results in missing textures, you have to recreate the materials of the model in Blender.