# Different Color When Rendered? (Not Material)

Tags: rendering, faces

I have made a model of a building. I was using the make face tool, but when I extruded it, it was a different color than the rest.
[image]

Its not any different material or anything either...
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **reset your normals**, go into edit mode, select everything <kbd>A</kbd>, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>.

This happens when blender incorrectly guesses which way the [**face normal**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals/) should be pointing when you make a face, it happens from time to time.

Comment: Thanks! Why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: @user3658408 If this helped you please mark it as accepted as soon as you can, I do understand there is a wait time, but a lot of users forget to, which is anyoing

Comment: I know, It says I need to wait 8 mins

Comment: @user3658408 Quite often it happens when you extrude a face in a different direction, scale by a negative amount, or fill mesh faces in an unexpected order.