# how to solidify a cylinder

Tags: modeling

ok, there's probably something  *huge* I'm missing that makes me look like an idiot, but I'm relatively new to blender and I'm having an issue, does anyone know how to solidify a cylinder? everytime I try, it just makes a smaller (and also hollow) cylinder inside of it, I've tried adding the solidifier modifier and fattening the faces, each time it remained hollow. If I could get any help I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I fill this object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-this-object)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate after reading the post a second time, I think op just needs to select the open sides and press `F`. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=fill+a+hole