# Is there a way to fill in a hollow object?

Tags: modeling, objects, geometry

I am trying to make a mold of an airway.  My goal is to fill in the mold (rectangles) up to the inner geometry.  Right now, they are completely hollow and I was curious if there is a way to fill in the inside of hollow objects.  Ideally it would be a similar style to the third picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add an illustration or example of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Just added one!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object/50254#50254