# How do I make a hollow sphere?

Tags: modeling

So my journey here is only days old, but am already struggling. I am trying to duplicate this:

[image]

I've watched countless videos and repeated the best I can learn so far. So on my first sphere I've created this:

[image]

At a different angle:

[image]

As you can see, I've created the hole, but the cylinder I used is now sticking out the other side, which I'm not sure how to remove, any thoughts?

Is this really the best way to create those hollow spheres, similar to the planets picture I pasted?

I downloaded blender yesterday (V. 2.83.1). Many of the YouTube videos I've watched are difficult to follow and often only relate to older versions, so finding one that will be 2.8 specific has proved to be difficult (might be that I'm so new to Blender so finding it difficult)

Comment: you can either extrude inwards or use a Solidify modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if you already used a cube with subdivision surface modifier to get your sphere. While not a bad idea, i'd recommend to use at least subdivision level 4 for a cleaner sphere, otherwise it's not really as spherical as you'd want.
Thanks to **Trey Harper** for pointing out the cast modifier, i barely use, which in this case though really improves the result.

That said, going from your (cube)sphere:

1. Apply the subdivision surface modifier on your cube(remember lvl 4, for a more spherical sphere) and a cast modifier with the factor of 1:
   [image]
   *Marked red, important before going on is to apply these modifiers in order!*
2. Go in front view <kbd>Num 1</kbd>, activate edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
   and x-ray mode <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, select half of the sphere like this:
   [image]
   *when selecting, leave the center deselected to keep a half*
3. With the selection, press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose **Vertices**
4. In the **Object Data Properties** we need to activate the Normals>Auto Smooth:
   [image]
   *Auto Smooth is needed for the next step to look clean at the cut*
5. Go back in object mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and add a solidify modifier.
   [image]
6. Adjust the modifier to your needs and you have one shell done.

You can now copy <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the created shell and adjust it's size to gain the other layers of the planet.

Here a little visual demonstration:
[image]
*The thickness of each layer can easily be adjusted in the modifier*

As the core looks like a full sphere, you should have all needed means to your cause now.

Happy Blending

Comment: Amazing!! Struggling with Step 2 tbh. My circle is as you described, thanks for the "level 4" tip. I've tried your instructions but all I get when I press "Tab" is a square box with a circle in the middle. If I select half the circle, half the square ends up being selected. Then pressing the "Delete" key on the keyboard, brings up a "delete" menu asking if I want vertices, faces etc... to be deleted and that I have to pick one. The result is nothing like your step. Any advice?

Comment: I believe you did not apply the subdivision surface modifier, as the modifier shows the sphere inside the cube cage when entering edit mode without applying.

Comment: For a perfect sphere (note the spheres created from a cube with a sub-surf are NOT perfect spheres) try using the Cast modifier after your Subsurf.  Choose Sphere with a factor of 1.0.

Comment: @TreyHarper thanks, i used the addon quad-sphere but will update the alternative, as it is only one more modifier for a better result without the need of the addon.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on this problem using modifiers as much as possible.

Start the same, with a roundcube found in the [Extra Objects add-on](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html?#add-mesh-extra-objects), and cut it in half.

It is helpful before going any further to snap the cursor to the roundcube with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>*>cursor to selected* and then add an empty which is the object of interest for the array modifier. Keeping the empty and quadsphere at the same origin will simplify the process greatly.

[image]

Next, we need some modifiers.

[Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) for thickness, [Edge Split](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html#edge-split-modifier) to sharpen things up some, [Subdivision Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) to smooth things out, and an [Array](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html#subdivision-surface-modifier).

This is the stack in the image below:

[image]

(note that the object offset is ticked in the array modifier)

Next you can simply scale down the empty and translate in the x direction.

[image]

Here is an example .blend to inspect:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant and inspiring. Thank you. I’d be really interested in how you scaled the other hemispheres in that proportion. When I press “S” the whole range of hemispheres shrink equally. Also I can’t select an individual hemisphere. It’s like they are one group.

Comment: The empty is what controls scale and translation. When you are satisfied with position you may apply the modifiers and adjust further.

Comment: Just tried this. When I click "Object Offset" the value field below the tick remains void. Clicking in the box reveals only two options ""Camera" and "Light". I decided to manually type the word "Empty" but the box won't take it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dan, see my edit. There is a sample file you may inspect

Comment: Thanks. I'll review offline. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to create a hollow shpere is to use a solidify modifyer, which will add a layer to the mesh, making it hollow on the inside. hope this helps!

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for the answer. Could you illustrate how to achieve this?