# Boolean Modifier Help - Difference - Surface Remaining

Tags: modifiers

I'm very new to Blender but I'm trying to create a simple facemask.
I am using a Head Mesh (using FaceBuilder add-on) and a simple hallow cylinder to create the profile of the mask that will sit against the face.
I have intersected the cylinder with the face and have used the Boolean Modifier with the Difference Operation to create a cut in the cylinder using the Face mesh.
The problem that I am having is that the front of the face is remaining after doing the Boolean Modifier.
Is there any way of removing this? Maybe I am misunderstanding/misusing the Boolean Modifier.

[image: Profile I want to create]
[image: What is happening]
[image: Face/Surface I dont want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work using 2.91 version of Blender with *"Exact"* option for the boolean:

[image]

*"Fast"* option behaves as the boolean of the previous version.