# Hollow head when exporting

Tags: makehuman

I have imported a MakeHuman figure into blender and I have posed an exported it as an STL.
But when I import the STL figure into chitubox the head has a hollow; but the rest of the figure is solid.
I cannot find a way to get rid of the hollowness in the head to make it printable.
Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: is it a real hollow or is it a flipped face?

Comment: It is hollow behind face an hollow eye sockets

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object/50254

Comment: I have used the addon 3D-Print to repair figure but to no avail still a hollow behind face.

Answer (score -1):

This is still a problem but can be fixed by using [UV tools](https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/uvtools?msclkid=27b174a0c5f611ec957248cedac6835b)
This will check and fix your model, a must have tool for resin printers.