# Is it possible to take a 'slice'/plane out of an object and extrude it

Tags: modeling

I am wondering if it is possible to create an object from a 'slice' from a different object which is then extruded - hard to describe.
Take for example a 3d model of an open row boat with the 3d cursor in the center of the boat.

Can a 'slice' of the open row boat be taken (on the X/Y plane), duplicated and then extruded on the Z axis to form a separate object which is the shape of the open boat (on the x and Y axis) at the 3D cursor position (which is the level of the water when the boat is in the water) at any height (Z axis)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could do this with Boolean modifier e.g.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Chris but I know nothing about boolean modifyers and wouldn't know which one to use. You said eg but didn't give examples  Oh there's only one. I will check out Youtube videos on booleans

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

Add a *Boolean* modifier to a plane object set to *Intersect*, and intersect it with your "boat" mesh. Set the solver to a mode that works well for you (in my Susane case *Fast*)

After that add a *Solidify* modifier set to any arbitrary height, and possibly an *Edge Split* if you desire smooth normals or optionally tunr on *Auto Smooth* under mesh properties in the *Properties Window*.

[image]

This only works well if your "boat" is a manifold closed geometry without many self intersections. Some occasional artifacts are expected regardless.

You can probably get more flexible results with a new 3.0 Geometry Nodes based equivalent setup.

With the current 2.93 it is not yet possible to extrude a mesh, as far as I can tell, but you can manually add a *Solidify* modifier after the Geometry Nodes as a separate modifier.

[image]

Comment: any clue to do that with GN?

Comment: With current 2.93 this is what I think is possible, 3.0 probably allows an entirely node based solution

Comment: That is awesome Duarte and looks exactly what I am trying to achieve. Thanks heaps for that tutorial which I will try out later and then tick 'solved' I'm sure.  Sorry for placing the question in the incorrect area (edit instead of modeling - I am still learning)

Comment: I have tried to follow your tutorial especially the animated part but cannot get my plane object with boolean modifyer to work like it does in your animation tutorial and wonder if my boat (actually a canoe) is a manifold closed geometry without many self intersections. I have added a screen shot to my initial question but cannot work out how to attach a file (a zip file containing .gltf and texture) of my canoe but have uploaded it to the cloud and avail;able here  - https://mega.nz/file/K1JhCawa#tzytyxxMmOMtSTW3TrhqdnHkpFp7n0Ar1FfVoSaaKEw

Comment: Your canoe is not a closed mesh. Enter *Edit Mode* and merge by distance. See possible solutions over at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object/50254#50254

Comment: Thanks. I applied 'merge by distance' after tearing my hair out trying to find the shortcut key(s) for Merge as most Youtube videos on the subject were created with 2.83 (press ALT + M for Merge instead of just M - so annoying) and then attempted to duplicate what you did but still it doesn't work. For a start my 'plane' mesh object is filled with white color unlike yours which is an empty 'box' which makes me wonder if I have done something wrong there). Then I added modifier Geometry which I had missed earlier. I attempt to check the nodes (click on Shading) there are no nodes displayed.

Comment: Don't bother with the Geometry Nodes option, follow the first solution using only modifiers, it is much easier to get working. Mine displays as a wire for illustration purposes, I didn't explain the steps to achieve that, it isn't supposed to look like that by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131604/discussion-between-john-arnold-and-duarte-farrajota-ramos).