# How to turn my hollow model solid inside for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have a hollow 3d model that i need solid. How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: hello could you please show a picture of the object and its topology?

Comment: It is a dress / bottom for a figure. How do i share a photo here. sorry i am very new to this.

Comment: you should be able to edit your question. For a dress you could give it thickness

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object