# Disolving object, but make it full inside

Tags: animation, shaders

I'm trying to make animation of disolving the object (like in the photo).
[image]
[image]

I dicaded to use a shaders by animating location X in the mapping shader
[image]

It's working but I need to make it filled inside (similar like in the photo) not a empty shell.
[image]

Anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object

Comment: I don't want to use boolean tool. That propably make mess with that object geometry and will cut it sharply (I want  little blur at the cutting point)