Making irregular body solid
I´m trying to create an object resembling solidified liquid metal using Blender.
The idea is to work on this object in Fusion 360 by merging it with less complicated solid objects created directly in Fusion 360.
Using a tutorial on youtube, I managed to create intricate geometry nodes in Blender, resulting in the liquid metal look I was looking for.
The problem is it being hollow, making it difficult or impossible for a beginner like myself cutting into it with other objects in Fusion 360. If only I could make it solid.
I tried and failed using Solidify Modifier. It almost solved the problem but since the object is so irregular, I could not find the right level. It either was too little or the object became distorted.
Please help me with this final step in Blender.
Thanks,
Christian

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object
