# Difference Boolean modifier. How do I get it to work with my mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, screw-modifier

I want to make a screw head, but I can't get the cross in the screw head; the *Boolean* modifier doesn't work.

Link:

[image]

Comment: probably apply the scales to your objects : in object mode, select each and ctrl+A and 'scale'. For the shape (not the head, the other one), you'll need to reset the normals too (edit mode, select all the vertices and ctrl+N)... this because the scale is negative in your file

Comment: You have non-manifold geometry on your two cubes and you need to use _Intersect_ for whatever reason on the _Boolean_ modifier.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/47

Answer (score 1):

Hi It does not work because your cube.001 topology is bad. You have two overlapped object instead one solid.

[image]

Comment: For questions that are answered in the comments, first, give the user who posted the comment time to answer. Read [What to do with questions which have been answered in comments?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are non-manifold geometry (something that couldn't really exist, like two cubes intersecting) and something else. I couldn't figure out the something else, but I do have a workaround.

*From the .blend file that you gave:*

1. Select the two-cubes mesh.
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.
3. Select one vertex of the horizontal cube.
4. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the other vertices in the same mesh.
5. Key <kbd>X</kbd> to open the *Delete* menu and select *Vertices*. You should now only have one cube:

[image]

6. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to position *Loop Cuts*. Position your cursor so that the pink outline is along the *Y-Axis*, key <kbd>2</kbd>, key <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> click.
7. Key <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to enter *Front Orthographic View*.
8. Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd>, then drag until the selected area looks square-ish.

[image]

9. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the *Mesh Select Mode* menu and key <kbd>3</kbd> to select *Faces*.
10. Select these faces:

[image]

11. Key <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to enter *Front Orthographic View*.
12. Key <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>, then drag, then <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to replace the old cube with new "cubes."

[image]

13. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.
14. Select the screw head object.
15. Go to the *Properties panel > Object Modifiers tab* and add a *Boolean* modifier.
16. Make sure the *Operation:* is set to *Intersect* and select *Cube.001* in the *Object:* field.

[image]

17. Apply the modifier.

*Final Result:*

[image]

Here is the .blend, also pictured in the above image:

[image]

Comment: hi Shady, for your information, applying scale and reverting normals on cube.001 works well too. Having two intersecting parallelepipeds does not seem to annoy the boolean modifier.

Comment: @lemon Fair enough. Mine does work though.

Comment: ok... but this shape basically IS manifold, as far as I know...

Comment: @lemon Isn't manifold all one piece? If you were to build a cross in real life wouldn't it look more like mine and less like the original? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You have information about that here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry. It tells about intersecting at the beginning. Here I am not pretending this is a good usage (as it annoys calculation) but this is not a non manifold case if I understand well

Comment: @lemon Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would model this:

-Simple mesh with a **Mirror Modifier** on two axis with "Clipping" checked.

[image]

-Select the outside vertices and press "E" and "S" to extrude scale.

[image]

-Select these eight interior vertices and press "E" and then "Y" and extrude constrained to the Y axis.

[image]
[image]

-Select these four vertices and press "G" then "Y" to grab them and move them up along the Y axis.

[image]
[image]

-Add five horizontal and five vertical Loop Cuts by pressing "CTRL" + "R" and using the mouse wheel to create 5.

[image]

-Tab into "Object Mode" and Apply the Mirror Modifier.
-Tab back into "Edit Mode"
-Select the outside vertices and press "Shift" + "ALT" + "S" and drag your mouse to create a circle shape. Right click to set it in place. Then press "S" and scale it up.

[image]
[image]
[image]

-Select these interior vertices and press "H" to hide them.

[image]

-Select the four middle vertices and activate "Proportional Edition" and select "Connected from the drop down menu. In the fall off type dropdown menu select "Sphere" Then press "G" and the "Y" and grab them up along the Y axis. You can control the range of vertices affected by using the mouse wheel.
-Disable Proportional Editing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

-Select the outside vertices and press "S" "Y" and Zero.
-Select the vertices just inside the previous selection and press "S" "Y" and Zero.
-Press "ALT+"H" to unhide the hidden vertices.

[image]
[image]
[image]

-After a Subsurf Modifier and some additional Edge Loops.

[image]