# Boolean Union making part disappear

Tags: modifiers

I know this question has been beaten to death, but I have tried all the solutions, and none of them work (manifold, normal's, triangulate, splitting it into simpler parts)

[image]

Im trying to add hoses to the side of my model, but the union boolean isnt working properly. It just makes the part disappear. Once I join them, I can mirror the part.
[image]

I did import these models from starcraft 2 using a m3 import tool, so there may be something a bit more complicated going on here that I just dont understand.(vertex groups? Materials?)

heres the file:  http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43732
(the entire model is there, just hide everything but the hips/hoses for now!)

Thanks for the look!

Comment: The selected part on the second image needs to be recalculated I think.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/47 (complete explanation of how Booleans can go wrong, and what to do about it)

Answer (score 2):

Download a [copy of 2.78RC2](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/) - the boolean modifier in 2.78 has a new BMesh solver that looks to give the results you are after.

[image: new boolean modifier]

[image: boolean comparison]