# Problem with boolean operator, operation "Difference" bettwen two simple objects

Tags: modifiers, error

Good day, dear advanced users of Blender!
I am starting to work with Blender and have such occasion.
There two objects:
-the lighthouse and
-the cube.
I am trying to create the window in the lighthouse by using 
Boolean Modifier-> Operation Difference -> Object Cube
and immediately I have a message:
"Can't execute boolean operation"

The *.blend file is accessible by the link
http://wikisend.com/download/612580/lighthouse.bool-error.blend

Please clarify me, how can I create the window due to this operator and 
why this error appeared?

[image: screen of the error]

Comment: The blend you uploaded works fine though. I just applied the modifier and it did it's job without errors.

Comment: Welcome to the site. For uploading files please use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (sharing on this site only). Your file had some doubles but they were in the bottom part of the mesh and didn't affect Boolean modifier for me. In general, the error you pointed out means there are some geometry problems with the mesh, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working. Also it's recommended to update the Blender version which is 2.78 now from official site.

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak! I read the link, that you inserted and found many answers from geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the model is it has created double vertices

1. Go in the edit mode
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select all
3. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring special key and click remove double
4. come out of the edit mode and make boolean operation

[image]

Comment: Atek, thank you very much for help! How did you find these double vertices? I want to avoid such situations in the future.

Comment: @atek Put <kbd> tags around keyboard keys please e.g. <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: @RayMairlot can you please explain me how to put that?

Comment: @atek What do you mean? Edit your answer and put <kbd> tags around the letters keyboard keys you are telling them to press, in this case, 'A' and 'W'.

Comment: @atek Look at my edit.

Comment: @RayMairlot thanks for editing and where can i get this code any link plz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html