# Boolean difference - Confused

Tags: modifiers

I'm very confused about the Boolean difference modifier. I'm modelling a concrete road block for use in a board game. I've created a basic shape and now I want to create grooves in the side by subtracting a wedge using the Boolean modifier.
I have uploaded my Blender file to Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jXsWFCZiMJMTZxTzVhcEl5Yzg

I've got two copies of my roadblock, named Roadblock 1 and Roadblock 2. The shape I want to subtract is named Wedge. Here's a screenshot (I'm working on one of the copies of the roadblock):

[image: Main Shape]

When I select the wedge in the modifier's "Object" field, the roadblock shape disappears completely. I can't put any additional pictures, my reputation isn't high enough.
I have tried this with both roadblock objects, and both have the same problem. No matter where I try to subtract the wedge from the object, it disappears entirely.
To find out it was the roadblock or the wedge that caused the problem, added a cube and tried subtracting the wedge from the cube, this worked normally. I'm a complete beginner at Blender, and I find this very confusing.

Comment: Some additional information, I have been playing around with it. The problem seems to occur only when the wedge shape intersects with the beveled edge. When I try to subtract in anywhere else it works.

Comment: Common problems when using Boolean - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version of Blender, and everything seems to work fine now. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: I spotted you're using 2.69, which is quite old... I'm on 2.78 so it could be a problem with 2.69 perhaps.

I tried your file, and I get this, which is pretty ok, imho, if I got what you exposed in the question:

[image]

otherwise maybe you could show what exactly is not working for you?