# Boolean modifier difference not working with complex mesh

Tags: modifiers

Thanks for reading me.

I've a mesh and a plane. I want to make a difference of the two meshes. But it's not working.

This is the step I completed so far:

On the plane

- Solidify

On the other mesh

- Recalculate normals (CTRL + N)
- Remove doubles (W)
- Triangulate (CTRL + T)
- Reduce number of triangles (ALT + J)

But it's still not working. Do you have an idea of what else I can do?

[image]

Thanks a lot for you help.

Maxime

Comment: There are several things that could be fixed (the remeshed mesh isn't solidified and hence manifold, solidified plane shouldn't have Flip Normals turned on in the modifier's settings) but those aren't really affecting that. If you move cutter cube a bit by X or Y axis Boolean should work. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working

Comment: Thanks for you help.
Indeed, if I move the cube is working perfectly. Could you explain me why? I didn't see the reason on your link

Comment: The possible reason is it can't solve the topology of the resulting mesh with the current cutter position; maybe not, this happens sometimes with Boolean (though not so often if meshes are relatively equal in geometry subdivisions). The related link was given as general source for Boolean.

Comment: I looked your file, try setting the "overlap threshold" to zero, in the boolean.