# Why do booleans sometimes not work?

Tags: modifiers

I've been designing some straight pipes lately. This I do by creating an outer cylinder for the outer diameter and an inner cylinder for the inner diamter and applying a difference boolean operator. Sometimes the boolean will just not work without giving sense to me. In this case I only have 2 kind of objects in the scene: Outer cylinders and inner cylinders. I've just applied the first boolean between outer and inner with success:

[image]

After applying the boolean to the second set, the object to which I applied the difference hasn't been subtracted the inner cylinder all the way through:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before?

/Cheers

Comment: booleans often don't work as expected due to many issues like, doubles, scaling, normals... if nothing works, upload the file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post the provided link into your question's text using the editor.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/1245