# Boolean applied, but not changing geometry

Tags: modifiers

ETA: I'm new to the Blender Stack Exchange, so I'm not sure where/how to upload my .blend files.

ETA2: Here is the file - [image]

I'm trying to trim one object around the edges. So I have 2 objects:

Object to trim:
[image: Object to trim]

Trimmer object:
[image: Trimmer object]

My boolean settings. I've tried the Carve solver with the same results:
[image: Boolean modifier]

Result. Note that the object-to-be-trimmed is completely unchanged.
[image: Result]

I'm completely confused by this behavior. I've looked at other similar topics, but no one is experiencing quite the same issue. Please help!

Comment: Does the 'Non-manifold geometry' section on this link help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working

Comment: Try hiding the trimmer object before applying the modifier to see if it is working.

Comment: I'm not so sure of how you designed your boolean "cut", but both shapes are full of issues, use the bundled 3d print addon "check all" feature to spot most of them...

Comment: @RayMairlot 's comment helped a lot. After I fixed the geometry issues, MOST of the boolean operations worked. One is still not working correctly in spite of everything. I'm going to post an additional question.