# Boolean not changing geometry as expected

Tags: modifiers

I posted an earlier question about this issue ([Boolean applied, but not changing geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96480/boolean-applied-but-not-changing-geometry)), and using the advice given to me, resolved most of the issues, except the following:

My object to cut:
[image: the object]

The cutter object:
[image: cutter]

The two objects overlaid on each other, plus my boolean settings:

[image: boolean settings]

Results of the boolean operation:

[image]

The geometry of both objects is manifold, per the 3D printing toolbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work two ways:

#### Set the *Overlap threshold* to 0

I don't know exactly what this setting does or why it works. I suspect the setting might be related to [this old carve bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5148/599), given that the bmesh method was recently added to replace carve, but that doesn't explain why it fixes anything in this case. You might want to [report a bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599) with this file, as I'm pretty sure the *bmesh* method should work without messing with this setting.

#### Use the *Carve* boolean method

Your cutter object has a negative Z scale, which, consequently, means the normals are inverted despite appearing correct. This makes carve act up (bmesh is fine with it though). To fix it:

1. Apply the scale with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
2. Switch to edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
3. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
4. Recalculate normals (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

You say that the two objects are *non-manifold*, however, the Boolean modifier is only intended to work with *manifold* meshes. Using non-manifold meshes will generally result in unexpected or unintended behaviour. Make the meshes manifold and try again.

Comment: However, the objects in the OP's .blend are manifold.

Comment: @gandalf3 I was working to the OP’s description - specifically stated as non-manifold. Your answer mentions that the Z-scale is negative - doesn’t that in itself make it non-manifold as it would mean the mesh effectively forms the infinite volume *outside* the mesh since the normals would be pointing in rather than out?

Comment: Sure, I just figured that if the OP was familiar with the concept of manifolds they probably understand that manifold geometry is required. Hence why I decided to double check the file. As I understand it,  manifoldness is (strictly speaking) a property of the surface and where the volume is doesn't matter. Indeed, boolean operations work just fine on inverted geometry, they are merely reversed.