# (SOLVED: Negative Scale) Boolean leaves a (gaping) Hole

Tags: modeling, modifiers, scale

No pun intended! I am trying to use booleans as a way to make a "cage" room for bolts in a bike part, but the problem is i am left with see through holes instead of a partial cut of the geometry.

[image: With Cutter]

[image: With Cutter Hidden]

Since I started out with a cylinder, I figured it had something to do with the mesh not having width (as in non manifold geometry if i got that correctly). But solidify really messes up the mesh so I tried to fix it by closing the mesh with a mirror. Still no luck. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I have already looked for double vertices, wrong facing normals and even tried inversing the normals of the cutting object just to make sure. Altho it could be something obvious I' m missing, it's kind of driving me crazy.

EDIT 2: Turns out my object had negative scale which made the normals appear normal. Needed to apply scale and then recalculate them. Thanks to @gandalf3 for pointing me to the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Everything you need to know is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34460).

Comment: Your object has negative scale, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/96554/599 for a similar problem

Comment: @gandalf3 Thank you sooooo much for this, that was really tricky cause the normals were appearing the right way. Guess it's another thing to look out for!