# Boolean modifier not working but when applied its dupplicates

Tags: modifiers

im trying to model a simple sword after watching some videos and im trying to add the Boolean modifier and after i click apply it ends up duplicating the cylinder im using the cut into the sword even though the cylinder is a separate object

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)

Comment: I'd suggest it's mirrored rather than duplicated.  What boolean settings did you use.