# Boolean modifier not working correctly with all vertices?

Tags: modifiers

I have been trying to figure out what that problem is for this and I would REALLY appreciate the help from anyone.

[image: The are of my project I'm trying to boolean]

This is the area that I wanted to boolean.

[image: This is the bottom of the above things][image: This is the modifier I used][image: This is what it looks like in object mode after the boolean modifier][image: This is what it looks like with edit mode after the boolean modifier.]
Steps I did was 
I select the cube and use the boolean modifier using the difference operation.
I select the object I wanted to use (in pictures).
I apply the difference modifier and some of the objects were able to work but the other vertices were stuck in the plane for some reason.

If anyone can help with my terrible way of explaining it would be nice and greatly appreciated. (I hope it's not me being stupid)

Comment: A comprehensive post on booleans can be found here: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781)

Comment: Not an answer .. but have you considered just reflecting your object, (scaling by -1) and using its underside ( with its normals flipped, if necessary ) instead of cutting your object out of another one?

Comment: This looks like the job for bezier curves or a vector illustration application. Booleans will just make a mess