# Boolean doesn't affect my object and i don't understand why

Tags: modifiers

I'm doing this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=307&v=WxMwa0njGSM

and by 5:11 min you can see, that the guy makes a cylinder to cut a part out from the anvil. I understand how to use boolean. I have to choose the anvil, then add boolean modifier and pick the cylinder object to make the move. I did everything just the same way as the guy, but as you can see on the attached picture my cylinder doesn't affect the anvil as on the tutorial. When I change the viewport to wireframe it seems good, but when I apply the modifier and I change the viewport again to solid, it's a full anvil again. I tried the method on an other layer with a square and an uv sphere and its works fine. When I copy the anvil to the other layer the problem is the same again. I tied to relaunch blender but nothing.

My blender version: v2.79

[image: picture in wireframe]
[image: picture in wireframe 2]
[image: picfure in solid viewport]

Comment: Does your object have any faces?

Comment: For a comprehensive post on problems with booleans read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working

Comment: thank you so much! I found the solution in the link. I had to remove doubles on the carving object!