# Boolean doesn't work after making several on one object

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I am designing a first aid kit in blender, and I have a foam insert that has booleans/holes in it for items inside the kit so it fits snugly. I have made 6 out of  8 boolean operations successfully, but 2 of them, after applying boolean modifier, do not create a boolean of any kind. But when I go to edit mode it shows on the topology the outline of my boolean. This is pretty weird,has never happened to be before.

Before boolean:[image]

After boolean in edit mode:[image]

The knife tool does work, but it does not yield the result i want and is not as smooth.

Comment: Have you already tried all the possible solution shown here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/15140?

Comment: @Carlo yes I tried removing doubles and fixing normals, again has not worked. On the scissors, there is intersecting geometry, which i fixed but still didnt fix the boolean problem.

Comment: What about the non-manifold geometry and overlapping faces? Your mesh seems to be composed by two different disconnected objects: if this is the case, you are not subtracting a properly defined volume.

Comment: you are correct, there were two objects i needed to join together, so i simply selected the vertices and hit alt+m>last for each one until it was closed. Subdivision surface wouldn't work and gave me a seam where the verts i connected were at.