# 2.8 Having trouble with Boolean Modifier

Tags: modifiers

[image]I am trying to follow Andrew Price's Anvil tutorial using Blender 2.8 and the 'Difference' modifier just isn't working for me.  I don't have the 'Maximum Draw Type' that I can change from solid to wireframe (mentioned at 5:07 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM)
 See Screenshot.
[image]

I started a new Blender project and I was able to start a new project and 'cut' a cube with the difference modifier just fine, AFTER I applied the modifier.  But I was unable to use the same technique to continue cutting the anvil back in my anvil project.

Can you see any reason why my difference is not working and/or suggest what I should do to make it work?  I've spent more time than I want stuck on what seems like should be an easy problem, ah Blender ;-)

New picture added as requested, front, top and two rotated views

Comment: Add a screenshot where you have taken your cylinder in the anvil.

Comment: I added the requested images but that still not leading to any solutions

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to yours, and while I don't know your exact issue (may I ask for a .blend file?)
I fixed my issue by merging doubles / merging verticies by distance.

You can do this by going into edit mode, (select the anvil), Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance. Try giving that a go.
[image: Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance]

---

Oh, and that thing about the wireframe cylinder? Select the object, go into Object Properties, Viewport Display > Display As > Wire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to follow all the reasons why Boolean fail on this page, [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)
but I honestly couldn't tell you which one of these solutions worked.

I really think that my issue was that I hadn't selected the anvil in the Object mode and then taking the Boolean picker and highlighting the non-selected cylinder which successfully intersected the anvil in the difference operation mode.