# Boolean Intersect/Difference Only Uses Edges

Tags: modifiers

This question is very similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/131696/77184), (if not, a duplicate) but I wish to add a few more details of my own. (The question is also still unanswered...)

I am following Andrew Price's Anvil Modeling tutorial, and there is this part where you are supposed to use the Boolean modifier to cut a cylinder out of the Anvil. However...
[image: The Boolean Modifier does not cut out the part where they overlap, but rather, only the parts where the edges of the anvil overlap.]
The Boolean Modifier does not cut out the part where they overlap, but rather, only the parts where the edges of the cylinder overlap (I have attempted to highlight the effect of the Boolean Modifier in blue.)

Since then, I have recreated this scenario, both in 2.79 and in 2.80, but in those attempts, the Boolean modifier had worked as expected:
[image]
**If I may ask then, what was wrong with my original .blend file that caused this error with the Boolean modifier?**

EDIT: I have already tried recalculating/flipping the normals, it hasn't worked.

[image]

Comment: This is impossible for us to tell without inspecting the original .blend file, all the reasons listed in the linked post are possible explanations as well as the one linked in the answer (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working). With the currently given information we can only make guesses, but can't give definitive answers.

Comment: The .blend file linked in the question (apologies if didn't appear) is the original.
Here's a link. Sorry:
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6296/

Comment: Sorry about that. I have a script blocker addon installed and I couldn't see the file. That was my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I really don't know what I'm doing, huh?

Following a comment on the same YouTube video of the tutorial, I removed doubles.
(In Blender 2.80, it is now named "Merge by Distance, and can be found in Edit Mode, Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance" [image: Merge By Distance]

So I learned a thing. I apologize if I wasted anyone's time with this.

\o/