# Why do Boolean operations tend to fail on overlapping faces?

Tags: modifiers

Very often I'll get erratic results with a Boolean operation on two objects with overlapping faces. The most usual result is missing faces in the combined object, or else internal faces are left after a Union, for example.

Why is this? Is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: for information on errors with boolean operations read: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working/34787#34787). Pay special attention to the section that describes **Overlapping geometry between objects**