# problem with boolean difference

Tags: modifiers

I need to make a cut to the second floor walls object so I created a boolean roof object at the proper angle that envelopes the portion of the upper wall to be removed. I checked for inverse surfaces and flipped them. I can't get it to work. It appears to cut the wall objects but doesn't remove the desired portion of the wall. See attached. Any advise?
Thanks

I added the shaded view. The part protruding  the roof is the part I want to cut off. [Link to the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zWxfYXP0TqfEJR32cJWr-JdiKRjOHdIH)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the BoolTools addon for this? And have you seen the solid view is the same?

Comment: BoolTools? I don't think I'm using this add on. I'm simply accessing boolean under add modifier generate column, boolean. I'm new and trying to learn the basics right now.

Comment: Can you add a solid view image, wireframe mode is not understandable

Comment: or share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: A comprehensive post on booleans can be found here: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781)

Comment: see edits to original.

Comment: As in most of the problems with this modifier, you have intersecting edges and overlapping faces. Choosing the ***Carve*** solver in the modifier settings will solve this problem.