# Boolean modifier not working for simple objects

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make a floor plan which I can 3D print.

I started by using a base cuboid, and then added rooms of specific dimensions with the hope of using the Boolean difference to remove the volume from the base cuboid.

Please see attached .blend.

When I use the Boolean modifier, it seems to have trouble showing me the end result (the faces look like they are ripping, tearing or just look weird??) and when I try to look at the item in Cura, it doesn't seem to have shown the Boolean difference modifier working.

I have tried using 'remove doubles' and 'limited dissolve' but no luck.

Any help would be great please.

Note: I have tried using the bevel modifier after the booleans and no luck; also tried applying the modifiers and it still comes out being all ripped/torn.

[image]

Comment: always bevel after you booleans! (in general)
it often mitigates topology issues associated with boolean modifiers.
you could simply put a bevel modifier after the booleans, and increase the segments to 2 or 3 and set it to "angle" and see if that helps.

Comment: Also if you are exporting to other software you need to **apply** the modifiers.

Comment: I have tried using bevel and applying the modifiers (and deleting the objects used for difference) but still is not working. Please help!

Comment: For a comprehensive post on booleans read: [boolean modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working)