# Blender 2.81 Boolean Bug

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry, error

Basically boolean union operation gives my mesh additional verts and edges I don't understand how and why it added them.

I'm using blender 2.81

My blender file:

- http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52764

Videos of bug:

- https://youtu.be/xb25F19fwnc
- https://youtu.be/cNsM66S5KY4

Things I already did (for both objects):

- I applied transformations
- Double checked if there are any doubles
- I'm pretty sure everything is planar

Any tips/guesses?

Comment: A comprehensive post on booleans can be found here: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781)

Comment: First: thanks for answer.

Second: So I read that post and it didn't help much. My object that have problem with boolean is constructed of smaller objects "Bricks"  technically all of those bricks are manifold but there are areas in between them for "Mortar" (you can see it on video) so if i joined bricks into a one object... is this object manifold? If it isn't how I am supposed to make some repetitive patterns that have free space in between? Any ideas?