# Trouble with difference Boolean

Tags: modifiers, objects

So im having an issue with boolean. I have a screenshot here and ive searched everywhere i could but i really cannot even explain it properly enough to find a solution. If yall need more information i will provide what i can, i just have never seen this before.

The cylinder is to difference from the back of the model here, but the left side of the model is clipping to the right side of the cylinder. If i make the overlap threshold .025, it no longer shows this clipping but when hitting apply, it does not even create the difference inside of the model. If i make the cylinder smaller, the pulling section dissapears, but then still after hitting apply, it does not create the actual difference. I was able to do this on a different part of the body and it turned out fine, but doing this part and the same thing to the body of the model im getting this weird magnet style clipping.

[image: Image of clipping]

This next image i took the face off the cylinder and youre able to see how its melding?
[image]

This image here i removed the back of the model so it is hollow and it still pulls as i thought maybe it was how i closed the object off

[image]

Please let me know if any more detail is needed, i am currently at a loss and too tired to google any longer.

Comment: did you try disable the armature modifier? if so probably fastest way is to upload simplified blend that still generates this issue https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com or check this A https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34787/2214 especially non-manifold section or here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

Comment: @vklidu Detaching the amarture to place the boolean worked perfectly. Ill have to remember that for now on. Thank you!