# When using the boolean modifier, the resulting faces disappear when applying the modifier

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make an N64 model, and to make the curve on the top of it i'm trying to use boolean to do it. I've encountered an issue where the boolean preview (before applying it) is exactly what i want, but if i apply the boolean, the face disappears. I've already checked for doubles and inverted faces, and everything was fine. The image attached shows what i mean:[image: Not applied on left, applied on right]

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat older link, with instructions likely intended for 2.79. But the answer given by zeffii is an amazingly good primer on the subject of booleans in Blender, which demystifies them by covering all the likely problem situations, as well as their remedies. Very much worth reading, in my opinion.

[The Boolean modifier is not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working)

Comment: thank you for the link with all that info! that will be very useful in the future when using booleans!

Answer (score 1):

whoops, i realized i had just forgotten to apply my mirror modifier before applying the boolean. problem solved!