# How do I fix this weird boolean operation?

Tags: modifiers

[image: Bo]

So this is what I'm talking about, it's like a weird inverted normal copy of the original mesh that was put into the difference boolean. Basically I used a cube with 4 vertices and used a boolean difference operation on the main mesh part. I hid the original cube and this is what happens, I've had this happen before but I usually just get rid of it after the modifiers are applied.

Comment: It looks like the normals are reversed on the smaller object. Before performing the boolean, and with all its faces selected in Edit Mode, invert the normals by recalculating them with Shift+n. If you want booleans to be demystified, read the answer given by zeffii here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working

Comment: @R-800 Yup! Seems like that was the problem, I guess sometimes the normals do need to be inverted so that I can't see them on the front. I always thought I had to always be able to see it normal front. One more thing though, do you know how to basically fill this in straight across? https://gyazo.com/0d3394ce93da3c4825f53d319a4c3ada

Comment: That area would be filled in automatically if your boolean had worked as intended. But for it to work as intended, exactly how booleans work needs to be understood. This is why I posted the link, which contains an answer by zeffii that is exhaustive.

Comment: But to answer your new question, you can go into Edit Mode, select two edges which are opposite to one another and press 'f' to fill that space with a single face. Don't select all the open edges that define your entire groove all at once before doing this, or it won't produce desired results. You will do it three times: Once for each wall of the groove, and once for the floor of it.

Comment: Well I can't seem to figure out how to fix the boolean modifier itself, so I'll just fill it in after. Thanks for the help @R-800!