# Get the "negative" of this object using Boolean Difference not working

Tags: modifiers

Somehow the difference boolean is not working on this object in which I try to get  the "mould" of the blue object, ie the blue object is the cutter.
I have followed the guidlines based on this link

> [The Boolean modifier is not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working)

As far as I know, my model

- does not have duplicates
- is a manifold object
- the normals are correct
- is a mesh.

I have attached the file incase someone might look at it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: if you try to dig the cube with the circular shape, you need to give the Boolean modifier to the cube, not to the circular shape. In that case the boolean seems to work fine with the Fast solver option

Comment: I never tried the fast option. Solution under my nose! Thanks! Should I delete this post?

Comment: no, you can keep it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to dig the cube with the circular shape, you need to give the *Boolean* modifier to the cube, not to the circular shape. In that case the boolean seems to work fine with the *Fast* solver option.