# Boolean Operator does not work correctly for animation

Tags: modifiers

I want to do a boolean operation (Intersect) between a disk and a plane, to get the profile of the disk.
My disk is turning slowly by animation. For each frame I need the profile, to do some stuff with a python script.

The problem is, that there are some frames where the boolean doesnt work as espected. But in many frames it works. For example:

- Frame 149 works (Profile is cut)
- Frame 150/151 doesnt work (Profile is cut, but the cutting plane is still there - like merge)
- Frame 152-154 doesnt work (No profile or plane is visible)
- Frame 155 works

My animation only controls the rotation of the disk. I cannot see any system of working-not-working frames.

To solve the problem I read the following post: [The Boolean modifier is not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working)
and do this

- remesh the disk (from large triangles to the fine mesh you see in the file)
- check normals (all were correct)
- remove doubles (14 were removed)

Sadly these "Bugfixes" doesnt work. What can I do to get a proper profile in each frame? What am I missing?

This is a simplified .blend File (EDIT: Now with Camera):
[image]

Thanks for your reply!
CeDoMain

EDIT:

- I'm using Blender 2.93.8.
- I added a Camera to the file to show the profile.
- I can see the wrong frames in Cycles, Luxcore and also in the Viewport directly. I provide some pictures how some of the described frames look to me:
  [image: Frame 149 with disk shown]Frame 149 with disk shown
  [image: Frame 149 with disk hidden]Frame 149 with disk hidden
  [image: Frame 150 with disk hidden]Frame 150 with disk hidden
  [image: Frame 152 with disk hidden]Frame 152 with disk hidden

Comment: This seems to produced a valid animation for me in 3.1.2 with Cycles, so you may either be facing a bug in the version of Blender you're using, or a Luxcore problem.  But you didn't include a camera, so I may have guess a camera position that doesn't show the problem.  Maybe place a camera and check if it is a Luxcore problem by rendering just those frames with Cycles?

Comment: @MartyFouts: Please see my edit. I also uploaded a new .blend file with a camera.