# Auto Boolean Difference Deletes Mesh

Tags: mesh, boolean-modifier

I am brand new to blender and have recently run into a bit of an issue that i have encountered a few times.
I am working on a model for a necklace from The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim that I found online, but when i try to cut into a mesh with another mesh using the auto boolean tools it deletes both mesh objects.[image]

In the picture you can see one carving into the base plate mesh that successfully took a boolean difference, but when i try to do the same with the other symbols it deletes the entire mesh instead of taking the difference. This problem doesn't resolve whether i use the plugin tool or the boolean modifier. Help me figure this out please! Thanks.

(edit) I forgot to mention in the first part that i already checked for Non-manifolds and water tightness, Correct facing normals, and doubled vertices, still having some issues. Another note, as you can see in the picture, there is one symbol that is carved into the surface, it is the only one that will carve into it, i tried to group all the symbols into one object to take the difference, and redrawing the symbols in one mesh but it still messes up the whole mesh.

Comment: Boolean operation usually fails when one or both meshes aren't manifold, has double vertices or have messed up normals. I recommend reading the second answer to this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working/34787#34787
But I must note that trying to boolean complex meshes is often quite a pain.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention in the thread that i already made sure every mesh was manifold and all of the normals are oriented correctly but it didn't fix the issue.