# Adding a 'distortion effect' to a model

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to add a 'distorted' effect to a model.  Are there any tools that can make this a more easy process?  Pictures with the effect I'm going for below.

[image: distorted 1]

[image]

Comment: Or is anyone interested in taking on this task...I can pay a freelancer.

Comment: Use a displace modifier driven by a cloud noise texture.  Are both images what you are looking for, or are they a before and after?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just so you know, this isn't really the place to be offering/taking jobs. For that I'd go someplace like BlenderArtists.org. But luckiliy, I don't think you'll need someone to do it for you. I'm sure someone here will answer this. I personally would play with the displacement modifier, and maybe shape keys.

Comment: @PGmath These images are both post distortion...two different toys. Thanks for the advice...I'll try that.

Comment: @DalekMaker Thanks Dalek...I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @AXLC I'm working on an answer with some more details. But I'd use normal displacement for the first image and RGB to XYZ displacement for the second.

Comment: @PGmath I'll try this within the next few days and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @PGmath ....man the displacement modifier is really touchy.  My guy is looking like a pin cushion or rice krispy treat.

Comment: Try a very small `strength` value (maybe `0.1` or less)

Comment: @AXLC, can you state if a post effect on the image would also be acceptable? or does this have to happen in 3D-space? if so why?

Comment: @ideasman42 ...3D space.  I design and make custom toys.

Comment: @DalekMaker ...also, thanks for pointing me to BlenderArtists.org ...I'm looking for a few freelancers for regular work throughout the year and it looks like there is plenty of help in that forum.

Comment: You may also deform your mesh using 'subdivide fractal': http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42420/where-is-subdivide-fractal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use a series of displacement modifiers to achieve this effect.  The displace modifier moves the vertices of a mesh around based on a texture.

To get a similar result to your reference image I have stacked two displacement modifiers.  Here is a render with three examples, from left to right: no displacement, first displacement modifier, both displacement modifiers.

[image]

They are both driven by *clouds* noise textures.  The first displacement modifier is left at the default *normal* displacement direction, this moves each vertex along its [normal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals).  The second displacement modifier uses a slightly larger clouds texture and *XYZ to RGB* displacement, this converts the red, green, and blue channels in the texture to displacement in the X, Y, and Z directions.  The texture driving this displacement modifier uses a multicolored color ramp to generate different red green and blue channels.

[image]

Comment: ...awesome...I'll try this.

Comment: @AXLC Great, glad I could help!  If it ends up working you can hit the green check mark next to the answer to mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: ...I ended up using the 'magic' noise texture...but all the other settings were a huge help in getting me there.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

I'll demonstrate you some mesh deformation methods using poor Suzanne ;).

---

- ## ***USING PROPORTIONAL EDITING WITH RANDOM FALLOFF TYPE***

[image]

The simplest way you can do I think is to go to *Edit Mode* and click *Select*-->*Random*, while vertex selection mode is enabled. 
Now you can enable the ***proportional editing*** with ***Random*** falloff type, then grab, rotate and scale some vertices to make deformations.
[image]

Remember, that you can set deformed vertices' transformations as a shape key to not destruct your base mesh.
[image]

---

- ## ***USING LATTICE MODIFIER***

  [image]

Being in *Object Mode* add a ***Lattice*** (*Add*-->*Lattice*). Subdivide it using options in *Object Data* header, and place your object inside it. Give your object a ***Lattice Modifier*** and set everything as pictured below. Select your *Lattice*, enter *Edit Mode*, select some random *Lattice* vertices, then grab, rotate and scale them (also using **Random** falloff of the *proportional editing*).
[image]

---

- ## ***USING MESH DEFORM MODIFIER (for a better control over deformations)***

[image]

Create a low poly representation of your object and name it for example *'cage'*. Place your object inside it. Give it a ***Mesh Deform Modifier*** and set everything as pictured below. Give the ***Precision*** factor a low value (the bigger the value, the more possibility, that your computer'll cry ;)). Next click the ***Bind*** button to bind your object to a low poly *'cage'* mesh. Now, when you deform vertices of the *'cage'* your object's vertices will be deformed as well.
[image]

Try to mix these for better result.

Comment: I'd mix in the displacement also

Comment: Hehe, good idea. This may be an explosive mix :). I know one more method. Give me some time and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Gonzou ...wow...awesome advice.  I'll play with these techniques for sure.

Comment: @Gonzou good going with the lattice, nobody uses that awesome tool. I must say I was surprised to see it already here. UVed

Comment: @David thanks for the kind words :). You're right, lattice is a powerful tool. Though since I discovered Mesh Deform modifier I fell in love with it even more, as it allows you to deform strictly defined parts of the mesh with a great precision. I think using it is a good alternative for a Lattice modifier.

Comment: @Gonzou mesh deform *is* great. and for this case quite possibly a cleaner solution. Both are about the same, which is why I usually mention both but just talk about one.