# Where is Subdivide fractal?

Tags: modifiers

In Blender 2.4 you had the option to do fractal subdivision (I think it was called Random). Is there anything like that or a plugin for 2.6+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Subdivide* tool has its own parameters which can be acceseed either via <kbd>F6</kbd> or Last Operator panel located in Toolshelf (shortcut <kbd>T</kbd>). When activated, you will find option *Fractal*:

[image]

Comment: I dont really see it under Operator, but thanks EDIT: Actually I see it in 2.76, but not in 2.75

Comment: That's quite strange as I work in 2.75. Not sure where the problem lies