# How do I keep particles still?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

I have a particle system that just doesn't want to stay still. I turned off all physics for it (including gravity) and removed all force fields, but they still move. Here's a gif of how they move:
[image]

Frame 1:
[image]

Frame 500:
[image]

I've noticed that there's a pattern of movement: they appear to be separating on the Z axis. The only reason they're also moving left is because I put in a wind force field, but this unexpected effect still happened before the wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your particles are getting a little [normal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals) velocity (i.e. being "pushed" off the emitter's surface).  You need to turn down the *Normal* value under the *Velocity* rollout of the particle settings.

[image]

Set this value to `0.000` and your particles shouldn't move.