# Weird zigzag circle in edit mode when applying subdivision modifier

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface, topology

After I applied my subdivision modifier, the top circle now has this weird zigzag pattern. Is this normal? If it isn't, why did this happen and how do I fix this?[image]

This is how it looked like before applying my subdivision surface modifier.
[image]

Comment: It's normal.  The top is a *triangle fan* and when the faces get subdivided one vert is closer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60834/why-does-my-model-look-messy-and-contains-dents-when-i-turn-on-the-multi-resolut/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, that's because the tip of your geometry is made of a ngon. The subdivision algorythm created a vertex in its center, created the new geometry from it.

If you activate the wireframe overlay and disable the Subdivision Modifier's `Optimal Display` option, you can actually see the final mesh beforehand:

[image: demo wireframe]

Because of how this subdivision algorithm works, you can't really avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

L0Lock is right the problem lies in the algorithm of the Subdivision Surface Modifier. However, there is a way to trick the modifier a bit.

Recently I ran into a similar problem as you, with the Subdivision Surface Modifier creating some not-so-pretty geometry. Especially when Shade smooth is enabled (Figures 1 and 2).

Fig. 1
[image: Unmodified geometry, Subdivision Surface Modifier applied, and Shade Smooth enabled (from left to right)]

Fig. 2
[image: Close up of geometry in Fig. 1]

The following solution led to a good result in my case:

1. as already mentioned, the problem is the n-gon at the "top" of the geometry. Here I start by inserting an inset (I). Now I dissolve every second edge of the resulting ring (Figure 3).

Fig. 3
[image: Inset added to the "top" n-gon of the geometry. Every second edge was selected to be dissolved.]

2. I repeat this until I obtain a square in the middle again (Figure 4)

Fig. 4
[image: The obtained geometry obtained after repeating the first step two times.]

3. (optional) I move the obtained faces a bit forward to get a rounder surface in the end (Figure 5).

Fig. 5
[image: Slight adjustment of the geometry to achieve a more round surface in the end.]

4. Finally, I apply the Subdivision Surface Modifier again. This gives me the following geometry (Figure 6).

Fig. 6
[image: The geometry obtained after applying the Subdivision Surface Modifier.]

Now I can also activate Smooth Shading and obtain the result shown in Figure 7.

Fig. 7
[image: The obtained geometry with Shade Smooth enabled. Overview (left) and close up of the tricky section (right).]

What this technique does is practically spread the problem across multiple faces. Whereas my previous geometry had a 32-gon before applying the Subdivision Surface Modifier, it instead contains 28 5-gons and a quad after the changes described above. The Subdivision Surface Modifier seems to handle this much better.