# Black areas appear when using Glossy and Normal Map, Cycles

Tags: light, normal-map, artifacts

[image]

When I add a normal map to glossy, glass or any reflective material there are appearing black zones and spots on it, like the light is not reflected there. And it doesn't matter of normal maps, and shadow. Please help.
Blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49002

Comment: Are your normals inverted?

Comment: What you mean, normal is in blue-violet colors,

Comment: see [What are face normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21190/2217) (Are any of them pointing in?)

Comment: They are directed outwards.